# NService Bus Message Size

Tags: c#, message-queue, nservicebus

I see that the max size for a message is 4 MB. I have a requirement where in I need to send messages of much bigger size to avoid database round trips. Is there  a way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you assuming you will use the XML serializer?  Switching to binary may get you close.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that . I am using Binary Serializer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can enable a feature called the databus and mark properties as a DataBusProperty, this will be send in another way f.e. via a file share or windows azure blob storage.

See following sample on how to do this: 
https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.Msmq.Samples/tree/master/DataBus

Hope this helps.

Comment: The link is not valid anymore. Needs to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

The general way to do this would be to have messages reference the data instead of having the data be part of the message body. The referenced data could itself be stored in a database or a key/value store or a file system. There would be a round-trip in that the referenced data would have to first be stored and then retrieved, but you can make this negligible overall. Concerning yourself too much about this round-trip is premature optimization.

As noted by **Yves Goeleven**, with NServiceBus v3+ you can mark message properties to be sent as references and stored in a file system or something else. This is done in a manner very much transparent to message handling code.